# Rect.map(): is the documentation wrong?

Tags: javascript, mozilla, rect, map-function

[Mozilla's Rect Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Geometry.jsm/Rect#map%28%29)

In Mozilla's documentation for their rectangle class `Rect`, one of the functions they mention is the `map()` function, which takes a function as a parameter. The description of the function is:

> Calls a specified function on each of the left, right, top, and bottom values of the rectangle.

But the inherent attributes of the rectangle are `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height`. While the "right" and "bottom" of the rectangle can easily be calculated, it just seems weird that the `map` function would modify calculated values, and not the actual attributes of the `Rect` object. Is this a typo in the documentation? It wouldn't be *that* weird; I found several other small typos while looking though that page of documentation, alone, but this one actually affects how the function works. Since the `Rect` class isn't one that's meant to be instantiated, I don't know how to test Mozilla's code to check this myself, either.

I understand the concept of a map function and what it does, but I don't routinely use them, so maybe this is just how they typically work. It *would* make sense to call the same function on four of the same types of values (left, top, right, bottom: positions) rather than on two of one (x, y: positions) and two of another (width, height: quantities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking up the Rect object on DXR, it seems that the documentation is [correct](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/55d557f4d73ee58664bdf2fa85aaab555224722e/toolkit/modules/Geometry.jsm#255).

By doing some codaeology (I made up this word, code+archeology :-D), I found that the map function was introduced with [bug 520910](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=520910). The reviewer didn't seem to have any concern with using `right` and `bottom` in place of `height` and `width`.

**Opinion**: I would dare say that it makes sense to map on four of the same types of values (left, top, right, bottom: positions), as you said. That even makes more sense because `width` and `height` are only used to initialize the `Rect`: `right` and `bottom` are the ones always used [internally](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/55d557f4d73ee58664bdf2fa85aaab555224722e/toolkit/modules/Geometry.jsm#90-91).

**Pro-Tip**: If you want to check Mozilla's code, you can take a peek at the code (and even quickly search in it!) using [DXR](https://dxr.mozilla.org).

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer!

Comment: Where did you find the actual source code? I'm having trouble navigating their huge codebase! Searching "Rect" didn't get me very far lol.

Comment: I made a case sensitive search with <"Rect(" ext:jsm> (without the </>). With "Rect(" I look for a "constructor", and ext:jsm restricts the search to javascript modules. Searching only Rect produces loads of results :)

Comment: And there it is. Thanks again! [DISCUSSION TERMINATED]